# How to mock a spring-batch SimplestepBuilder processor() in junit-5 Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

How to Mock a simple step builder Processor() in Junit-5 Mockito. which is Throwing Null-Pointer exception

```
private Step step() {
    return this step builder factory get("").<Object, Object>chunk()
            .reader()
            .processor()
            .writer()
            .build();
}
```

How to Mock this Processor for spring-batch step, in junit-5 Mockito

Comment: You haven't provided an actual implementation of reader OR processor OR writer, so answering this question is almost impossible.

Nonetheless, if you provide a class that implements `ItemProcessor<InputType, OutputType>` and pass it to the processor method e.g `.processor(myProcessorImplementation)` then you could write your tests against that processor implementation.